# How can I write undecuplets (11-tuplets) and duovigenuplets (22-tuplets) on Noteflight?

Tags: tuplet, noteflight

I found these undecuplets (11-tuplets) and duovigenuplets (22-tuplets) in Chopin's *Nocturne in B-flat minor*, Opus 9, Number 1:

[image: Extract of Chopin's Nocturne, showing 11-tuplets and 22-tuplets]

I want to use such tuplets in my own music. How can I write them in Noteflight?

Answer (score 5):

Noteflight doesn't offer anything more than septuplets. There are several requests for more in the [Noteflight feedback forum](https://support.noteflight.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360001405652-Musical-Notation-Feedback).

A work-around would be to split the tuplet up. Probably almost nobody can accurately play 22 notes over a whole measure.

Comment: Chopin can know to play 22 notes in a whole measure.

Comment: 11 is a prime number. 22 is divisible by 2, but if you try to put a dotted whole note in Noteflight and then add a duplet, Noteflight will show a message saying that it can be divided into 2 dotted half notes without a tuplet. 22 is divisible by 11 but 11 is a prime number.

Comment: @Vighnesh Two sextuplets and two quintuplets would give you 22.

Comment: How to get 11 notes in a whole measure?

Comment: @Vighnesh A sextuplet and a quintuplet. The alternative is to buy a professional notation program.

Comment: All the notes in the large tuplet must be of equal value.

Comment: Noteflight should really add this feature. It is very important for Chopin. Even larger tuplets are in the Nocturne in C-sharp minor, op. posth. It should be called 'Custom Tuplet' and its icon should be a tuplet bracket with either '#' or 'n' in it.